# Modifying UserAccountControl Flags - Toggling a Flag

Tags: windows, powershell, user-management

I am wondering if there is a way to toggle a UserAccountControl flag on or off despite the other flags' states. For example, let's say we have a configuration like the following:

[image: Admin Flag Configuration]

How would I only toggle the 'Password never expires' flag to true despite the current `$user.UserFlags.value`?

When all of the flags are toggled off, the `$user.UserFlags.value` is 513. When only the 'Password never expires' flag is toggled, the `$user.UserFlags.value` is 66049.

As you can imagine, there are a range of numbers that the `$user.UserFlags.value` can reflect for different configurations as mentioned in the following article:

[How to use the UserAccountControl flags to manipulate user account properties](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144)

I feel like I can come up with a solution using bit-wise manipulation with masks but need some guidance. My end goal is to write a Power Shell script to toggle this value on no matter what the current configuration may be.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you're looking for is [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). Use the bitwise XOR operator (`-bxor`) to conflate the current `UserFlags` value with the flag you want to toggle (in this case 0x10000 or 65536 for the flag `DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD`) and commit the change:

```
$user.InvokeSet('UserFlags', $user.UserFlags.Value -bxor 0x10000)
$user.CommitChanges()
```

For more information see the "Bitwise Operators" section in [`about_Comparison_Operators`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx).

Comment: Perfect and concise. Thank you very much!